# Collect comments on a draft document online

Tags: software, collaboration

I am writing a collective report and I need to collect comments on the final text. I know that there is a free Google Docs option for that and it is fine. But I would like to find a tool that would allow me:

- insert the name of the person who comments (it is complicated if a person doesn't have a Google account)
- comments are visible only for the commenter and me

Do you know of any such tools? It should be online, not pdf format. I also do not want to combine comments from word documents.

Answer (score 1):

Rare combo for a tool to allow collaboration without having a login but also allow them to add a name to the comments/feedback. I'm afraid it'll be hard to find a tool that meets both your criteria.

For what it is worth, please check out these tools (some paid, some free): Evernote, Docs in GitHub using Markdown, Dropbox collaboration, Hackpad, HackMD, Dropbox Business, and CryptPad.